# Invalid use of argument matchers 0 matches expected. 3 recorded

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, aws-glue

I'm writing unit tests in scala using [MockitoSugar](https://scalamock.org/). I'm using `org.mockito.Mockito.when` and `org.mockito.Matchers.anyString`. The method under test is shown below.

```
def getDataSourceToDataFrame(database: scala.Predef.String, tableName: scala.Predef.String): DataFrame = {
glueContext.getCatalogSource(
  database = database,
  tableName = tableName,
  transformationContext = database + "." + tableName + ".read")
  .getDynamicFrame()
  .toDF()
```

}

Here is what my unit test looks like:

```
import com.amazon.rrsetlglue.glue.wrappers.WrappedGlueContext
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.{DynamicFrame, GlueContext, DataSource}
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfter, FunSuite, Matchers}
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.mockito.Mockito.when
import org.mockito.Matchers.anyString
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
// Use Mockito because ScalaMock does not work with Glue
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class WrappedGlueContextTest extends FunSuite with 

org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar with BeforeAndAfter  {

  var mockGlueContext : GlueContext = _
  var wrappedGlueContext: WrappedGlueContext = _

  before {
    mockGlueContext = mock[GlueContext]
    wrappedGlueContext = new WrappedGlueContext(mockGlueContext)
  }


 test("Test get dataFrame from glue data catalog source") {

    val mockedDataSource: DataSource= mock[DataSource]
    val mockDynamicFrame: DynamicFrame = mock[DynamicFrame]
    val mockDataFrame: DataFrame = mock[DataFrame]
    assert(wrappedGlueContext.glueContext === mockGlueContext)

    when(mockGlueContext.getCatalogSource(anyString, anyString, anyString)).thenReturn(mockedDataSource)

 }
}
```

The last `when()` call throws the error below:

`org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 3 recorded:
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.`

The definition for `getCatalogSource()` is shown below

```
 def getCatalogSource(database: String, tableName: String, redshiftTmpDir: String = "",
                   transformationContext: String = "", pushDownPredicate: String = "",
                   additionalOptions: JsonOptions = JsonOptions.empty, catalogId: String = null): DataSource = {
```

Why is it saying `0 matchers expected` when I'm calling the method `getCatalogSource()` on a mocked object?

Comment: What's the definition of `getCatalogSource`?

Comment: Also "Use mockito because scalamock does not work with glue" comment looks suspicious. Why doesn't scalamock work. Are you sure that mockito does?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can post the code for `getCatalogSource` as it's a internal package. Yes I've verified that scalamock doesn't work and I've seen mockito being used successfully in other packages.

Comment: Not the code ... just the definition.

Comment: @VictorCui does `getCatalogSource` have any implicit/curried/default parameters? One of the reasons this error can occur is if you have mixed implicit/default values with `any()`s.

Comment: Yes! that was the problem @JamesWhiteley.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that `getCatalogSource()` had default parameters that I wasn't passing in using my matchers. I changed the method call in the test to

```
 when(mockGlueContext.getCatalogSource(anyString, anyString, anyString, anyString, anyString, any(), any())).thenReturn(mockedDataSource)
```

and the test passed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the scala version of [mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala) the default arguments will be handled for you, it will also allow you to mix raw params and argument matchers